# How to separate opened windows in alt+tab switcher in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: unity, 18.04, application-switcher

When I have multiple windows of an application opened e.g. Chrome main window and Incognito window, and I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between them, I see only one Chrome icon. I have to then press down key and then right (or left) to switch to the window I want.

How can I separate all opened windows and just press <kbd>Tab</kbd>  again while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key, like we used to in earlier versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: The new behavior, like Mac, is terrible.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Go to Settings > Devices > Keyboard and scroll down the list of shortcuts. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will be the shortcut for Switch Applications.

What you want is to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  on Switch Windows instead, so click Switch Applications and press backspace to clear the shortcut for it. Click set. Then click Switch Windows and set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> there instead. This will give you the desired function.

[image]

Comment: anyone know how to do this through terminal ? Trying to automate.

Comment: Use the gsettings command. Key binds can be found at the path "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings"

Comment: Works like a dream.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: omg I wish I had thought to do this a long time ago. Thank you!

Comment: What's the difference between Switch Applications to Switch Windows?

Answer (score 49):

It's very simple to solve your problem without change the native keybindings.

All you need to do is type  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick, the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) if you want switch between the same apps.

To switch different apps, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Developing muscle memory for a hard-to-reach keyboard shortcut is not simple, nor is switching between two windows of the same app since it involves two sets of keypress combinations as opposed to simply alt+tabbing between the two.

Comment: The idea of ​​all developers about window management is very simple, typing alt + 'or Alt Tab. That's what I meant, and yes, it's very simple.
I use this function for many many years, and all the devs that I know use this function.
you can not rely on yourself to say this, if this function is still available, it is because it has been approved by the community.

Comment: Does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: On the other hand I would consider this as a better answer because once I integrate the new shortcut within me, it is applicable on any Ubuntu machine. And although this wasn't asked, it's related and broad enough to answer the intent. So thanks!

Comment: thank you @KalEl!

Answer (score 10):

### Graphically using dconf-editor

From : https://superuser.com/a/860001/718726 (pasted here because there is no equivalent answer in here)

- Open `dconf-editor`
- Go to `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`
- Move the value `'<Alt>Tab'` from `switch-applications` to `switch-windows`
- Optionally move `'<Shift><Alt>Tab'` from `switch-applications-backward` to `switch-windows-backward`
- If you want `switch-windows` to work across desktops, not just in the current desktop, you can also uncheck `org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only` (Courtesy of @CharlBotha)
- Close `dconf-editor`
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type <kbd>r</kbd>  to restart Gnome.

The last step does not always appear to be necessary, but it should not hurt (especially since it does not close any of your running applications).

### Equivalent using command-line (no need to install dconf-editor)

Run the following lines in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"
```

If you want `switch-windows` to work across desktops, not just in the current desktop, you can also execute:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false
```

If you don't notice any change you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type <kbd>r</kbd>  to restart Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

Install the gnome shell extension [AlternateTab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/)

Comment: now obsolete 2020