# How to make Alt+Tab switch applications in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I have Lubuntu 20.04 installed. Now with `Alt + Tab` I can switch between windows, but I want to use it to switch between applications.
I have already seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036248/how-to-separate-opened-windows-in-alttab-switcher-in-ubuntu-18-04) and [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/alt-tab-display-separate-windows-ubuntu-18-04/), but they didn't worked for me because I have not the `switch windows` command in the shortcut list, I think because Lubuntu uses LXQt.

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of search in the documentation [Appendix F Hotkeys shortcuts](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html) and [Chapter 3.2.14 Shortcut Keys](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.14/shortcut_keys.html#chapter-3-2-14-shortcut-keys),I figured out that it is just not possible.

If you read the [Openbox Bindings](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) section and the [Actions Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions), you won't find any command to switch applications instead of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I found a solution [on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135236/alttab-no-longer-groups-windows-under-applications-in-ubuntu-19-04) concerning Ubuntu 19.04. Worked for me by going to Settings > Keyboard shortcuts and then replacing the "Switch window" shortcut with `alt` + `²` (key above `tab`) and "Switch application" shortcut with `alt` + `tab`. See image below (in French, sorry!).[image].

Comment: My problem was with Lubuntu, non Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, I read your post too quickly apparently!